# PhoneGap cordova create stuck

Tags: android, html, cordova, mobile, web

I got stuck when trying to create my first PhoneGap application. I entered 
`cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` in the command line and got this text:

```
Downloading cordova library for www...
```

I waited some minutes, but libraries didn't load. I guess it's a common problem for beginners.

Please, help me solve this problem and let me go further. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Please run it with the `--verbose` option, and add the output to the question

Answer (score 0):

In the PhoneGap documentation, they state that it may take a while to create the app.

"It may take some time for the command to complete, so be patient. Running the command with the -d option displays information about its progress."

Try this:
    $ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld -d

You can see the progress.